# Ubuntu not recognizing flashdrive

Tags: usb

When I plug in my flashdrive to a USB port, the drive pops up in File System for a second and then disappears. I can't do anything to bring it back, and it acts like it was never plugged in. I've tried multiple ports so I know it's not the specific port, and I can use the same flashdrive on the same port in ChromeOS (Booting Ubuntu in a Chroot using Crouton). Any help?

Comment: What's `lsusb` have to say about your flash drive?

Comment: Have you looked in `/media/username` to see if it is showing up by name?

Comment: Have you run a `sudo part -l` to see if it shows up there?

Comment: I'm an idiot who is unfamiliar with Ubuntu layouts and didn't realize /media/username existed/showed my usb. It ended up being there and everything shows up. thanks for the help!